# Python - Why does list(set(my_list)) destroy the original order of the data?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the duplicates in a list `my_list`

```
In [13]: my_list
Out[13]: [[(-7.7725138974675732, -79.168560840024711),
  (-7.7725138974675732, -79.168560840024711),
  (-5.5, -59.0),
  (-4.4, -48.3),
  (-3.2, -37.5),
  (-2.1, -26.9),
  (-0.9, -16.2),
  (2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868),
  (2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868)],
 [(2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868),
  (2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868),
  (29.8, 16.4),
  (41.8, 16.9),
  (53.1, 17.2),
  (74.767340748230566, 15.947522750252775),
  (74.767340748230566, 15.947522750252775),
  (74.767340748230566, 15.947522750252775),
  (97.8, 13.4),
  (109.2, 14.9),
  (125.57323627494615, 19.53393479479609)],
 [(68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (71.141449110088374, -58.675607868692225),
  (73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (74.5, -2.9),
  (74.767340748230566, 15.947522750252775)],
 [(-109.09700131981562, -32.09602243732722),
  (-108.3, -32.7),
  (-81.9, -52.7),
  (-64.94343179027949, -62.943395681375023),
  (-64.94343179027949, -62.943395681375023),
  (-44.8, -70.5),
  (-32.2, -74.1),
  (-7.7725138974675732, -79.168560840024711),
  (-7.7725138974675732, -79.168560840024711),
  (10.6, -80.1),
  (21.6, -80.4),
  (32.8, -80.6),
  (43.9, -80.6),
  (68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (94.59403067734813, -75.99089907199837)],
 [(-57.743037814594651, 0.48281269760971313),
  (-57.743037814594651, 0.48281269760971313),
  (-61.5, -30.9),
  (-62.9, -42.2),
  (-64.94343179027949, -62.943395681375023),
  (-64.94343179027949, -62.943395681375023)],
 [(73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (113.3911596081064, -33.232674908171724)],
 [(71.141449110088374, -58.675607868692225),
  (71.141449110088374, -58.675607868692225)],
 [(2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868),
  (-17.6, 3.5),
  (-57.743037814594651, 0.48281269760971313),
  (-57.743037814594651, 0.48281269760971313)]]
```

**Then, I do `my_list = list(set(my_list))`**

```
In [20]: my_list
Out[20]: [[(-7.7725138974675732, -79.168560840024711),
  (-3.2, -37.5),
  (-2.1, -26.9),
  (-5.5, -59.0),
  (-4.4, -48.3),
  (-0.9, -16.2),
  (2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868)],
 [(109.2, 14.9),
  (41.8, 16.9),
  (97.8, 13.4),
  (29.8, 16.4),
  (53.1, 17.2),
  (125.57323627494615, 19.53393479479609),
  (74.767340748230566, 15.947522750252775),
  (2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868)],
 [(73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (74.5, -2.9),
  (74.767340748230566, 15.947522750252775),
  (68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (71.141449110088374, -58.675607868692225)],
 [(-108.3, -32.7),
  (-7.7725138974675732, -79.168560840024711),
  (-44.8, -70.5),
  (-81.9, -52.7),
  (10.6, -80.1),
  (-64.94343179027949, -62.943395681375023),
  (94.59403067734813, -75.99089907199837),
  (-109.09700131981562, -32.09602243732722),
  (68.773124224303274, -79.616585806160444),
  (32.8, -80.6),
  (-32.2, -74.1),
  (21.6, -80.4),
  (43.9, -80.6)],
 [(-62.9, -42.2),
  (-64.94343179027949, -62.943395681375023),
  (-57.743037814594651, 0.48281269760971313),
  (-61.5, -30.9)],
 [(73.874255065554237, -27.94398092967819),
  (113.3911596081064, -33.232674908171724)],
 [(71.141449110088374, -58.675607868692225)],
 [(-17.6, 3.5),
  (-57.743037814594651, 0.48281269760971313),
  (2.7974572775821454, 4.4251549647685868)]]
```

As can be seen, the order of the data has changed. The order is important for me. **So I have to maintain the order after the operation.**

**Why** is it so **and how** do I maintain the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cameronsparr says, you ordering because *sets are inherently unordered*.

To maintain the order I would do something like this:

```
old_list = [...]
new_list = []
tmp_set = set()
for el in old_list:
     if el not in tmp_set:
          tmp_set.add(el)
          new_list.append(el)
```

[How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order) has a much-slicker way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks but why both solutions give `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`?

Comment: @mavErick because lists are not hashable, which is a requirement for addings things to a set.  Convert your lists to tuples.

Comment: I've converted the old list to tuple, but it somehow still reports this error. http://pastie.org/8413483

Comment: if this didn't solve your problem you should not have accepted the answer.

Comment: But the problem that remains is only a syntax one. The concept is correct. So I accept it.

Comment: You should ask a new question with the code in that link.  It it too long to explain what is wrong in the comments section.  You are only changing in locally in one place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39539/discussion-between-tcaswell-and-maverick)

Answer (score 3):

the order is destroyed because of `set`, which by nature is an un-ordered collection (edit, thx)

as to maintaining the order: [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: Then how may I maintain the order?